# Issue with Docker compose and Kestrel in asp.net 6.0 app

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, .net-6.0, kestrel

I'm trying to run my aspnet 6.0 app using docker(Linux Container on Windows system) and having issues. **it runs perfectly fine when I'm not trying to configure kestrel**. But whenever i'm trying to add below code, i'm getting issue saying "This site can’t be reached localhost unexpectedly closed the connection."

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{

    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5005, options =>
    {
        options.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;

    });
    serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 7173, options =>
    {
        options.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
    });
});
```

I'm trying to use port 5005 for GRpc purpose and 7173 to expose rest api endpoints. I'm using visual studio 2022 and generated DockerFile by adding docker support.

Here are the docker compose,compose-override yaml and container snaps.
[image]

[image]

[image]
I have also tried adding https support, but no luck.

```
 serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 7173, options =>
    {
        options.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
        options.UseHttps("appname.pfx", "password");
    });
```

Please Note: **all of the above lines of code works great when I'm not running on docker**.

Comment: As per compose file you are mapping 80 and 443 but in code you are listening on different port. Definitely you cant access from outside. In compose file you need to use same port and also in docker file you need to expose those ports

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to expose same ports in DockerFile as pointed out in comment by @CodingMytra

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, copy it into the answer instead.

Comment: Thanks @buddemat , will do same from next time

Answer (score 2):

I think you can configure this in `appsettings.json` too:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "WebApi": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:7173",
        "Protocols": "Http1"
      },
      "gRPC": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5005",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @C1sco, I have already tried that and it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 2):

I configured it like this in docker compose, otherwise I also could not get it work.

```
    version: '3.8'

services:
  myservice:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8000;http://+:5000
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__gRPC__Url=http://*:5000
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__gRPC__Protocols=Http2
      - Kestrel__Endpoints__Http__Url=http://*:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```